# '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'result' Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a program that displays a graph of real estate in cities in the States. I was able to create a main function, which mainly concerns creating a graph of each city.

Now, I am trying to add a new feature, which lets users choose one city among many options by creating a combobox.

What I want to make is basically just allows users to click one option among many cities in combobox, and when users click it, it should automatically call the main function so that the main function can generate the selected graph.

I am using tkinter and Custom Tkinter modules for my GUI design.

**Code:**

```
#Libraries
(...) # This is for graphing features

#Tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import customtkinter as ctk
import requests
import tkinter.messagebox

ctk.set_appearance_mode("Light")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

class App(ctk.CTk,tk.Tk):
    
    WIDTH = 780
    HEIGHT = 520
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry(f"{700}x{500}")
        self.title("Title of My Program")
        self.protocol("Window Closed", self.stop) # "stop" function called when program closed
        self.resizable(0,0)
        
        # Options for light & Dark mode
        
        self.option1 = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(master=self,
                                         values=["Light", "Dark", "System"],
                                         width=30,
                                         height=30,
                                         command=self.windowcolor)
        self.option1.place(x=5, y=10)
        
        self.option1.set("System") # Select default color for buttons
        
        # Create center label
        
        self.label1 = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self,
                                   text="Graph is generated if you click one option from the below combobox.")
        self.label1.place(x=200,y=10)
        
        
        # City list
        
        cities = ["LA", "CA", "IN", "AK" # etc ...]
        
    
        # Center Combobox
        
        global combobox1
        
        self.cb_var = StringVar()
        self.combobox1 = ctk.CTkComboBox(
            master=self,
            values=cities,
            command=main,
            variable=self.cb_var,
        )
        self.combobox1.place(x=280, y=50)
        
        
        # Create center frame
        
        self.frameCenter = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self,
                                        width=682,
                                        height=370,
                                        corner_radius=5)
        self.frameCenter.place(x=9, y=120)
    
    global main
        
    def main(self): # Main function
        
        self.tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title="Combobox", message="Clicked")
        
        if combobox1.command == "CA":
            graph_CA(self)

        # graph photo is generated here
        
        self.data = pd.read_excel("MyExcelFile.xlsx", sheet_name="MySheetName")   
        
        # Remove ctkCombobox, create a window fits for graph photo
        
        def graph_CA(self):
            # Graphing features added here
        
    # Function that changes color of window
        
    def windowcolor(self, new_appearance_mode):
        ctk.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)
        
    # Function that stops program

    def stop(self, event=0):
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

**Problem:** When I run this code, everything works fine except it generates this error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'tkinter'

after I click any options from the center combobox.

The main function works fine and generates graphs well but the program stops even before reaches the main function.

**Question:** How can I make a combobox that can call the main function when a user clicks any options from it?

Comment: `App` should inherit from `ctk.CTk` only.  The exception in title does not match with the exception mentioned in the question.  The exception in the question is due to `main()` is called when a value of the combobox is selected and the selected value is passed as the first argument which is `self` in `def main(self)`, so `self.tkinter....` raises the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "self." from `messagebox` function like this:

```
def main(self): # Main function
    #self. removed
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title="Combobox", message="Clicked")
```

Answer (score 0):

Install CTkMessagebox:

`py -m pip install CTkMessagebox`.

> How can I make a combobox that can call the main function when a user
> clicks any options from it.

When you click 'combox,' you have several typographical errors.

Remove tkinter and tkinter.messagebox, so you don't need them anymore.

You must focus on `customtkinter` for the rest of the script.

- You must use `self.frameCenter` as a root window fore every
  `customtkinter`'s widgets.
- Move the `ctk.CTkFrame` on line 25. So we started the beginning.
- Add `ctk` to `ctk.StringVar()` on line 51.
- Replace `self.tkinter.messagebox` with `CTkMessagebox` on line 64.

Btw, you are missing `import pandas`. I leave it up to you.

Script modified:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import customtkinter as ctk
from CTkMessagebox import CTkMessagebox
import requests
 

ctk.set_appearance_mode("Light")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

class App(ctk.CTk):
    
    WIDTH = 780
    HEIGHT = 520
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry(f"{700}x{500}")
        self.title("Title of My Program")
        self.protocol("Window Closed", self.stop) # "stop" function called when program closed
        self.resizable(0,0)
        
         
        # Create center frame 
        self.frameCenter = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self,
                                        width=682,
                                        height=370,
                                        corner_radius=5)
        self.frameCenter.place(x=9, y=120)
        
        # Options for light & Dark mode
        self.option1 = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(self.frameCenter,
                                         values=["Light", "Dark", "System"],
                                         width=30,
                                         height=30,
                                         command=self.windowcolor)
        self.option1.place(x=5, y=10)        
        self.option1.set("System") # Select default color for buttons
        
        # Create center label
        
        self.label1 = ctk.CTkLabel(self.frameCenter,
                                   text="Graph is generated if you click one option from the below combobox.")
        self.label1.place(x=200,y=10)
              
        # City list        
        cities = ["LA", "CA", "IN", "AK"]
           
        # Center Combobox                 
        global combobox1
        self.cb_var = ctk.StringVar()
        combobox1 = ctk.CTkComboBox(
            self.frameCenter,
            values=cities,
            command=main,
            variable=self.cb_var,
        )
        combobox1.place(x=280, y=50)
                
    
    global main        
    def main(self): # Main function
        
        CTkMessagebox(title="Combobox", message="Clicked")
        
        if combobox1._command == "CA":
            graph_CA(self)

        # graph photo is generated here
        
        self.data = pd.read_excel("MyExcelFile.xlsx", sheet_name="MySheetName")   
        
        # Remove ctkCombobox, create a window fits for graph photo
        
        #def graph_CA(self):
            # Graphing features added here
        
    # Function that changes color of window        
    def windowcolor(self, new_appearance_mode):
        ctk.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)
        
    # Function that stops program
    def stop(self, event=0):
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]